# Laravel out of memory

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5

Im trying to export my data to [an excel sheet](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) but I get the error:

> FatalErrorException in Connection.php line 321: Allowed memory size of
>   134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 196605 bytes)

I understand I could just up the memory limit of php but I like to understand why my code takes up so much memory.

My code:

```
public function exportExcel()
{

    $datum = date("d-m-Y");


    Excel::create('Sales export '.$datum, function($excel) {


        $datum = date("d-m-Y");

        // Chain the setters
        $excel->setCreator('some name')
            ->setCompany('some company')
            ->setDescription('sales export.')
            ->setTitle('Salesexport '.$datum);

        $excel->sheet('sales '.$datum, function($sheet) {
            $orders = Order::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
            $sheet->appendRow(array(
                "merk","product","artikel nr","categorie","collectie","maat","omschrijving","inkoopprijs","verkoopprijs","prijs betaald","aantal verkocht","verkocht aan",  "totaal","dag","maand","jaar","kwartaal","reseller","verkoper","bestel naam"
            ));
            foreach($orders as $order)
            {

                foreach($order->products as $p)
                {

                    $sizeLink = $p->productSize;
                    $productLink = $sizeLink->product;


                    // Append row as very last
                    $sheet->appendRow(array(
                        $productLink->brand->name,
                        $productLink->name, 
                        $productLink->artnr, 
                        $productLink->category->name, 
                        $productLink->collection->name, 
                        $sizeLink->size->name,   
                        $productLink->desciption,   
                        number_format((float) $productLink->price_buy_in, 2, ',', ''), 
                        number_format((float) $productLink->price, 2, ',', ''), 
                        number_format((float) $p->price, 2, ',', ''), 
                        $p->quantity, //geboekt aantal
                        $order->billingname . $order->billingnamelast, 
                        number_format((float) $p->quantity * $p->price, 2, ',', ''), // totaal kosten
                        //number_format((float) ($p->quantity * $p->price - $p->quantity * $p->price_buy_in), 2, ',', ''), // winst inkoop-verkoop
                        date("d",strtotime($order->created_at)),
                        date("n",strtotime($order->created_at)), 
                        date("Y",strtotime($order->created_at)), 
                        ceil(date("m",strtotime($order->created_at))/3), 
                        $order->reseller->name,
                        $order->creator, 
                        $order->name, 
                    ));
                }
            }

            // Auto filter for entire sheet
            $sheet->setAutoFilter();
            $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
            // Set black background
            $sheet->row(1, function($row) {

                // call cell manipulation methods
                $row->setBackground('#cccccc');
                $row->setFontWeight("bold");

            });
    $sheet->setColumnFormat(array(
        'G' =>  \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00,
        'H' => '[$EUR ]#,##0.00_-',
        'I' =>  \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00,
    ));

        });

    })->download('xlsx');;
}
```

Comment: How many rows do you usually process here?

Comment: orders containts 135 rows. orderproducts 1350

Comment: Could you store the data in cache (daily around let's say 3 AM) then try to export them or you need 'fresh' data?

Comment: @ka_lin need fresh data, its only exorted about once a week.

Comment: Can you propose a limit to the result set to have daily reports vs all?

Comment: @AderemiDayo im using MySql

Comment: As can see allocated memory(196605 bytes) is less than allowed memory(134217728 bytes). This issue is not with the number of products you are uploading it in value you are uploading... Where encoding is the greatest culprit. Check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090688/out-of-memory-error-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: If you are using mongodb, this is due to the presence of a special character in what you are uploading. In your case, I am suspecting the description which might be copied from a webpage and therefore can contain special characters. just use utf8_encode($description) on the description before sending it to the database, it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to process too many processes at a same time which is taking so much of memory, you should use [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-chunk) method of Laravel's collection like this:

```
Order::orderBy('created_at','desc')->chunk(10, function($orders) use ($sheet) {
    foreach($orders as $index => $order) {
        // Do your stuff here...
    }
});
```

Hope this code helps!

Comment: Will chunk make a limit query or just apply array_chunk o the result set?

Comment: I get an error for the line :   foreach($order->products->chunk(10) as $p)
                    {  saying "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$products"

Comment: The `chunk()` method process code in chunks so that the php processes 10 sets at a time instead of 1350 sets (as you mentioned) which avoids large memory usage..!!

Comment: Please check that the `$order` is an object or a Collection, it seems to me a collection.

Comment: shouldnt chunk be used on the get query "  $orders = Order::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();"

Comment: So you have no clue then

Comment: The chunk() method appies array_chunk so that being said the content is loaded in memory : `public function chunk($size)
    {
        $chunks = [];

        foreach (array_chunk($this->items, $size, true) as $chunk) {
            $chunks[] = new static($chunk);
        }

        return new static($chunks);
    }` -> PATH: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php`

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi thanks for your help I ended up doing it like: " Order::orderBy('created_at','desc')->chunk(10, function($orders)use ($sheet){
                    foreach($orders as $index => $order)
                    {"

Comment: @Sven - If you found this answer correct then please upvote and accept as it motivates me to answer other questions like this and help others to find the correct access quickly...

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi If you change your answer a bit i will, you current answer will throw an error.