# Out of memory error in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, memory, special-characters

There is an issue on Laravel 5.3 / Jesenger / MongoDB 3.0 which I reported [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24698/).
The issue arises from saving or updating a field with special characters like "°ó" in mongodb, it always results in "out of memory" error.

```
Allowed memory size of ######### bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ********** bytes) 
//Whereas ######### is always greater than **********
```

My question is how can I convert the special character so that they can be safely pushed into the database. 
***Note***: I am doing batch insert and updating of like 30000 records, a good solution may put this into consideration.

```
// Code Sample
<?php 
class Products extends Jessenger\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
{

}
?>
$product = new Products();
$product->name = 'Akara';
$product->sku = 'naija001';
$product->description = 'special characters like °ó in mongodb';
$product->save(); // Throws allowed memory size of 1392394984 bytes 
                  // exhausted (tried to allocate 2195914) note that 
                  // allowed memory size is greater than the allocated size
```

### My temporal fix

```
$product = new Products();
$product->name = 'Akara';
$product->sku = 'naija001';
$product->description = utf8_encode('special characters like °ó in mongodb');
$product->save(); // Saved successfully
```

Comment: Are you creating a Builder that runs an update statement or are you loading thousands of models into memory and looping over them to update each? It's unclear to me what you mean by "batch insert" without a code example.

Comment: It is not the batching that is causing the out of memory issue, even if it is just one record, once the record is having at least one special non-UTF character, it will throw the error... I want to save whatever is sent but due to that bug I will have to convert to safer characters. I don't want a converter with too many processes that may elongate further my already long processing time, that is why I put the note... Thanks

Comment: Using `utf8_encode(str)` works for me, if there can be better solution kindly post, I needed to explicitly call this function on all my record fields before saving them whereas it may be one out of one thousand that contains the special non-UTF characters.